# What would a universe that expands at a constant rate, that has no pressure, and no cosmological constant be like?

Tags: cosmology

Consider a universe that is expanding at a constant rate, or that a double dot is zero, and there is negligible pressure and no cosmological constant. What are some of its properties?

Answer (score 1):

The [Friedmann equations tell us](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric#Interpretation):

$$ \frac{\ddot{a}}{a} = -\frac{4\pi G}{3} \left(\rho + \frac{3p}{c^2}\right) + \frac{\Lambda c^2}{3} $$

Since you specify that $\ddot{a}$, $p$ and $\Lambda$ are all zero that means $\rho$ must also be zero i.e. the universe contains nothing at all.

You also specify that $\dot{a}$ is non-zero, but this cannot happen with an empty universe. So the main property your universe has is that it doesn't exist.

Comment: Okay, but I'm not sure why the universe still can't exist. If the universe contains nothing because density = 0, then can't space still expand, although it has nothing in it?

Comment: @googooeyooey: No. The other Friedmann equation links $\dot{a}$ to the density and dark energy. If they are both zero $\dot{a}$ has to be zero as well.

Comment: You are missing the curvature term.